# CSS keyframes animations and ability to shorten the syntax

Tags: css, animation

I'm currently working on a CSS animation that involves using keyframes. The code for the animation is quite long and I'm wondering if CSS has the ability to use functions or equations to shorten it up a bit. I'm working on CSS only currently and do not want to include any JS.

I haven't been able to find much regarding the ability to use a keyframes equation to solve this issue. There are a few other sections on my project that end up with the same lengthily code.

```
@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    3% {
        left: 0;
    }
    5% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    7% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    10% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    13% { 
        left: -200%;
    }
    15% {
        left: -300%;
    }
    17% {
        left: -300%;
    }
    20% {
        left: -400%;
    }
    23% {
        left: -400%;
    }
    25% {
        left: -500%;
    }
    27% {
        left: -500%;
    }
    30% {
        left: -600%;
    }
    33% {
        left: -600%;
    }
    35% {
        left: -700%;
    }
    37% {
        left: -700%;
    }
    40% {
        left: -800%;
    }
    43% {
        left: -800%;
    }
    45% {
        left: -900%;
    }
    47% {
        left: -900%;
    }
    50% {
        left: -1000%;
    }
    53% {
        left: -1000%;
    }
    55% {
        left: -1100%;
    }
    57% {
        left: -1100%;
    }
    60% {
        left: -1200%;
    }
    63% {
        left: -1200%;
    }
    65% {
        left: -1300%;
    }
    67% {
        left: -1300%;
    }
    70% {
        left: -1400%;
    }
    73% {
        left: -1400%;
    }
    75% {
        left: -1500%;
    }
    77% {
        left: -1500%;
    }
    80% {
        left: -1600%;
    }
    83% {
        left: -1600%;
    }
    85% {
        left: -1700%;
    }
    87% {
        left: -1700%;
    }
    90% {
        left: -1800%;
    }
    93% {
        left: -1800%;
    }
    95% {
        left: -1900%;
    }
    97% {
        left: -1900%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -2000%;
    }
}
```

Comment: judging from the values it seems your are tackling the issue the wrong way. Show us what kind of animation you are looking for and I am pretty sure it can be done with an easier code

Comment: It is an image carousel that automatically scrolls between 20 photos. The reason why the left value is identical one after the other in certain parts to to ensure the animation pauses on each image for a little bit

Comment: start by putting the same value only once `5%,7%{}` but better share your whole code. Maybe it can be done differently

Comment: Ah yes even that helps a lot. I like that layout more. The rest of the code that has anything to do with that is just an animation: 50s slider infinite. And im happy with that.